# Recombining subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that generates a figure with 4 subplots:

```
def genFigures(self,savefile='out/histograms.png',show=0) :
    fig, ((barsimpF, barsimpT),(barsworF, barsworT)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True,figsize=(12,10))
```

but I would like to have the opportunity to reuse and recombine the subplot in different ways later on, with other subplots from other calls to the function. I have tried the function to return the subplots

```
return (barsimpF,barsimpT)
```

But how do I reuse them later on? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reuse"? You can use them, just by calling some of the axes' methods, e.g. `barsimpF.set_xlim([1,5])` or so.

Comment: I mean to create another figure with them and others recombined in different order. Would this work?

fig, (barsimpT,barsimpF) = plt.subplots(1,2)

Comment: This would overwrite the existing variables, like `a = 3; a=2` results in `a` being `2`; and not `2` being `3`. Subplots are necessarily bound to a figure. You cannot have the same subplot in more than one figure. Best do not use functions which create subplots, but use functions which take subplots as argument to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand why. I am struggling to understand how to create a "function that takes a subplot as argument". Sorry the documentation is not very helpful on this. I need to automate the creation of many figures and I still would like the ability to recombine some subplots on the fly without having to regenerate the data.

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098845/matplotlib-pyplot-create-a-subplot-of-stored-plots) as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861656/plot-something-in-one-figure-and-use-it-again-later-for-another-figure) to see what I mean by "function that takes a subplot as argument".

Comment: Thanks, that helps, especially the second link